# Is there a php shopping cart that does not need registration?

Tags: php, open-source, shopping-cart

I want to find an open source php shopping cart software. Is there a software that does not need customer registration? 
Customers only add the items into their shopping cart then click paypal, pay the money.
(I think paypal already has this function, custom e-mail address, custom can write where address, what are they want in their payment introdution.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are several, but I've personally used this one - works nicely.

http://www.oscommerce.com/community/contributions,355

It also supports paypal

Comment: Sorry -1 because osCommerce is by far the most crappy PHP software in existence. Also the linked code examplarifies this quite well by relying on `$HTTP_GET_VARS[]` from PHP3.

Comment: Thanks, I find one shopping cart from jquery.com ,  http://www.techlaboratory.net/products.php?product=scat

Comment: I never said I'm an advocate of OSCommerce. Although, it's far from the crappiest shopping cart - I could have linked to much worse (jquery shopping cart for example). It does exactly, 100%, what the author requested though - and if that's worth a downvote then SO has some problems.

Comment: I wouldn't use this software.